# Accessing route ID in child module

Tags: angular, routes

I am pretty new to Angular routing and am trying to access an ID from the route but it seems like no params are available.  Here's how my routes are organized (this is imported in app.module.ts):

```
import {FinancePageModule} from './client-detail/finance/finance.module';
import {AuthGuard} from '../../auth/auth.guard';
import {ClientDetailPageModule} from './client-detail/client-detail.module';
import {ClientIndexPageModule} from './client-index/client-index.module';

const clientsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'clients',
    component: ClientIndexPage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { path: 'clients/:id',
    component: ClientDetailPage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'finance',
        component: FinancePage
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'finance',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(clientsRoutes),
    FinancePageModule,
    ClientIndexPageModule,
    ClientDetailPageModule,
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClientsRoutingModule { }
```

My `FinancePageModule` has no routing (which might be why I cannot access the ID) and when the `FinancePage` is loaded, the ID is null.

```
export class FinancePage implements OnInit {

  client_id: number;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.client_id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    console.log(this.client_id) // logs NaN
  }
}
```

How do I modify my routing so that this variable is available in the `FinancePage` component?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `id` is set in the parent route so you can use `this.route.parent` ,

The reason is ActivatedRoute only passes the
 parameters for the current component route and because the route for
 finance doesn’t have any route parameters it didn't pass any parameter
 so you have to get the params for the parent route by using `route.parent`.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.client_id = parseInt(this.route.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

   this.route.parent.params.forEach(
      param => console.log(param)
    )

    this.route.parent.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)
    })
  }
```

Comment: When I tried that, `this.route.parent` is `null`.  I think there is something wrong with the way my routes are setup

Comment: try to provide us with stackblitz link with your running code